# Table with automatical column-break

Tags: tables, columnbreak

I would like to make a really broad table in LaTeX which automatically breaks when it reaches the right end of the page.
As I am not so good in describing the problem, I made a sketch:

[image: sketch]

It is not important that it looks exactly the same (e.g. the dotted lines). The important thing is that it breaks automatically.
Do you have an idea? I don't want to rotate the table since it would take too much space.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Crosspost on goLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a start...I just concatenate a bunch of single column `tabular*` blocks.

EDITED to give the OP an additional input format more akin to `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mycell[2]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{35pt}{c}$#1$\\\hline $#2$\end{tabular*}\allowbreak\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\mysep{%
  \begin{tabular*}{0pt}{|c}\strut\\\hline\strut\end{tabular*}\allowbreak\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\Startthistable[2]{%
  \par\noindent\leftskip35pt\leavevmode\llap{\mycell{#1}{#2}}\mysep}
\newcommand\Endthistable{\par\leftskip0pt\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\Setthistable[1]{%
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist*\mytabledata{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mytabledata[1]{%
    \mycell{\x}{\mytabledata[2,\xcnt]}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\Startthistable{x}{f(x)}
\Setthistable{
 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23\\
 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1
}
\Endthistable

\noindent or else one can do it the original way

\Startthistable{x}{f(x)}
\mycell{1}{1}
\mycell{2}{1}
\mycell{3}{1}
\mycell{4}{1}
\mycell{5}{1}
\mycell{6}{1}
\mycell{7}{1}
\mycell{8}{1}
\mycell{9}{1}
\mycell{10}{1}
\mycell{11}{1}
\mycell{12}{1}
\mycell{13}{1}
\mycell{14}{1}
\mycell{15}{1}
\mycell{16}{1}
\mycell{17}{1}
\mycell{18}{1}
\mycell{19}{1}
\mycell{20}{1}
\mycell{21}{1}
\mycell{22}{1}
\mycell{23}{1}
\Endthistable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility to make it that way I can use the standard '1&2&3...' format?

Comment: @KwazyCupcake Please see my update.